# Add a description string to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to add a description to a python numpy array.

For example, when using numpy as an interactive data language, I'd like to do something like:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
A.description = "Holds all the data from experiment 1. Each row contains an intensity measurement with the following columns: time [s], intensity [W/m^2], error [%]."
```

But it gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'description'
```

Is this possible without subclassing the numpy.ndarray class?

Regards,
Jonas

Comment: Maybe the simplest thing would be to make a class which contains the array and your description.  That way you wouldn't have to subclass ndarray, which as you probably know is a bit wacky.

Comment: That would also be a more sensible way of making functions that deal with that data in the array.

Comment: If you don't want the description to survive array operations, subclassing work easily for this. If you want more, it requires a bit more and will leave a few operations where the information will not be preserved anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to hold both the array and the decription:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Array = namedtuple('Array', ['data', 'description'])
>>> A = Array(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]), "Holds all the data from experiment 1. Each row contains an intensity measurement with the following columns: time [s], intensity [W/m^2], error [%].")
>>> A.data
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> A.description
'Holds all the data from experiment 1. Each row contains an intensity measurement with the following columns: time [s], intensity [W/m^2], error [%].'
```

Comment: Nice. But probably I will write my own data class (like John Z. suggested), with a function to save and load the data and the description to a .dat file. Until this is done, the namedtuple will be my solution.